# Hide entire element from webpage that contains a specific word

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, console

Here is the element I want to hide from webpage if it contains the word "weight": The constant thing about this element is that it contains the word "weight":

weight: 25.10 կգ    cost: $135.00

Basically I want a code that will run in Chrome console and will find the word "weight" in the entire webpage and hide the elements that contain that word: Any suggestions please ?

I read some people offering to create classes, etc etc: But I think there should be simple code to insert into Chrome console to do the job:

Comment: Here is the Full element example

<font style="border-bottom:1px dashed black;width:100%;display: inline-block;">weight: 27.19 կգ  &nbsp; cost: $135.00</font>

Answer (score 1):

You can solve a similar problem by searching for all TextNode (using [TreeWalker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TreeWalker)) with the necessary text, with further hiding their parent elements. Simplified example below:

```js
const walker = document.createTreeWalker(document.body, NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT);
while (walker.nextNode()) {
  if (walker.currentNode.textContent.match('weight')) walker.currentNode.parentElement.hidden = true;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>...</li>
  <li>Hidden element: weight: 25.10 cost: $135.00</li>
  <li>Visible element: "test 1"</li>
  <li>Visible element: "test 2"</li>
  <li>Hidden element: "weight"</li>
  <li>...</li>
</ol>
```